# Creating / adding new tags for existing questions without swamping the home page

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging, retagging

I am currently doing a little research into some aspects relating to the [Sasanian Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sasanian_Empire) for another project, and I thought it might be useful to see what questions have been asked and answered here.

We didn't have a tag, but it looks like we have something like 20 questions on the subject. However, these can be hard to find because of the variant spellings generally in use ('*Sasanian Empire*' / '*Sassanian Empire*' /  '*Sasanid Empire*' / '*Sassanid Empire*' / '*neo-Persian Empire*' etc.).

This strikes me as exactly the kind of situation that tags were invented for, so I have created the [sasanian-empire](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sasanian-empire) and [proposed](https://history.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest) the [neo-persian-empire](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neo-persian-empire) tag synonym.  I'm not sure whether I should also create synonyms for the variant spellings, and would welcome advice.

---

For what it's worth, searching on Google Scholar for *Sasanian Empire* currently gets 17k hits; while *Sassanian Empire* gets 12.2k hits, *Sassinid Empire* gets 8.2k hits, *Sassanid Empire* gets 7.5k hits, and *Sasanid Empire* gets 3.3k hits.  *Neo-Persian Empire* got just 500 hits.

All of which may represent the general usage of the various terms.

---

I've re-tagged a couple of questions, but in order to avoid swamping the home page with older questions - and so risk drowning out new questions, potentially preventing them from getting the attention they deserve - I intend to re-tag the other questions gradually over a period of time.

---

I wanted to ask the community's opinion on this approach to re-tagging.

Should re-tagging of existing questions be done gradually as I have suggested, or do people favour a 'big bang' approach where all are re-tagged at once, but where the home page will be (hopefully briefly) swamped with older questions?

Comment: Shouldn't the title better reflect that it's more an issue of the effects of the (re-)tagging? That is: include the 'bump' but maybe drop the 'create'? I think the scope is wider as we recently saw such things happen with 'spanish empire' or so. An existing tag producing the same outcome.

Comment: @LangLangC Fair point.  I've updated the title.

Comment: Weird; I always heard it as Sassinid. I guess this is the new accepted name?

Comment: @T.E.D. I've always used Sassanid up until now, but Sasanian  does seem slightly more common in the academic papers I've been reading (which, admittedly, may not be a representative sample), and is also the term chosen by Wikipedia where a lot of people are likely to come across it first.  And who are we mere mortals to argue with Wikipedia? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not sure whether I should also create synonyms for the variant spellings, and would welcome advice.

That seems like a sensible thing to do if they don't show up quickly enough with the autocomplete suggestions. Just my $.02.

> Should re-tagging of existing questions be done gradually as I have suggested, or do people favour a 'big bang' approach where all are re-tagged at once, but where the home page will be (hopefully briefly) swamped with older questions?

Something in between maybe? Like `X` at the time, for instance. Basically, leave enough recent questions around -- they'll get bumped back up with new activity. And then rinse and repeat the next day. And so forth.

Edit: My initial suggestion for `X` was 10. Based on the comments, a lower limit, e.g. 3-5, seems more appropriate.

Comment: I'd say, 3 a day and most wouldn't notice, 5 and hardly anyone would complain, but more than 6 would make me curious and at ten all from the same topic (re:tags) it might get into 'slightly annoying' territory.

Comment: @LangLangC: yeah, but then it's only for 2-3 days in this case, so I sincerely doubt it'll bother that many people in practice

Comment: Thank you for this, it helps. But I was trying to look at it more generally, so we could point people here in future for guidance in case there's a situation that needs intervention.  Personally, I think I agree with @LangLangC about the lower limit.  Imagine, at some point in the future, having 10 re-tags bumped to the home-page every day for a month!